# Where must the argument be checked

Tags: java

In my java code I need to call one method inside the other. The argument passed to `suspendUserTestList` must not be `null`. So the very simple question is where I must to check for `null` case: before passing the value or inside the second method?

Here are my methods:

```
public String suspendTest(Integer locationId, Integer userId) {
    testManager.suspendUserTestList(userTestList, SUSPENDED_TEST_FREQUENCY, usersTestsSuspenSession);
}

public void suspendUserTestList(List<UserTest> userTestList, Integer frequency, Session session) throws MonitorUsException {
    if (userTestList == null) {
        throw new MonitorUsException("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not even mentioned how you are getting the userTestList in the first place. No context of what is going on and what is the purpose of the above 2 methods. Also, just 2 methods, how does it even matter when you are throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer will be **Depends**.

Long answer is .......

After looking at your method implementation, you are throwing the exception if it is `null`.  So you have to call the method before checking to receive that exception.

If you check before calling the method, you won't receive any exception and it just skip the call to that method and proceeds further.

If you are fine with not calling even if it is `null`, check for null and then only call the method.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a good idea to check the **inputs** of every method. So if your `suspendUserTestList()` method expects a non-null parameter, it should check that the parameter is indeed non-null before using it.

It makes your method more self-contained and less dependent on its calling environment. It's also easy to read and to test in isolation.

Whether you then **also** check in the caller is not so straightforward to answer, it depends on a lot of factors. I'd go with whatever looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

#### Generally speaking

Generally, you want to check for null where you actually use the object's methods or properties.

However if the calling method knows that the called method will not check for null (when you use a library for instance, you have no control of how the object you give will be used, but by inspecting the code you may see that no null check is made), then you have to either check for null or catch NullPointerExceptions.

In any case, you must make sure to catch the possible NullPointerExceptions in a given layer of your application (for instance a level where you can provide the information to the user, if there is a UI).

#### Particular case

In your own particular case, your two methods are public. Because both can be called from outside, you have to make sure that the null check is made at the lowest level (`suspendUserTestList`), because you may start to call the `suspendUserTestList` method from other places in your code. By putting the null check in `suspendUserTestList`, you make sure that all other possible future calls to this method will have the same null check logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed rule, both places can be valid. Common sense is to do it in the called method so you write the logic ones and not in all places where you use the method. Probably throw an IllegalArgumentException to not add new types for a common case.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely ok to check inside the public method (it's called "precondition"). As for checking before the call, it depends how you are using this `userTestList` field. Probably it was initialized in the constructor (like `userTestList = new ArrayList<>()`) and never reassigned. Then no need to check it anywhere (better to declare it as `final`). On the other hand it can be passed in some setter like this:

```
public void setUserTestList(List<UserTest> list) {
    this.userTestList = list;
}
```

In this case it's much better to add one more check in the setter. In any case it's better to do the checks as early as possible.